# Is it possible to shift lines without moving cursor?

Tags: text, vim

I often move blocks of text around within a file by e.g. marking the top and bottom of a range and then doing `:'t,'b>`. I find that having completed the shift, the cursor always moves the the line marked by `'b`.

When trying to fine tune the actual amount of the shift required I then have to move back to `'t`, check the indent with respect to the surrounding text and then repeat the shift.

Is there a way to achieve the same result without the cursor moving lines each shift?

Comment: Not an answer to your question but you know you can press `.` to repeat the shift?

Comment: Not with the shift done as a command I didn't. I am aware of @: but this does not fix the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think just pressing

```
`t
```

to go back to `mark t` is big effort.

If you don't want to press any key after the cmd execution, you can execute:

```
:'t,'b>|norm! 't
```

Or you don't shift lines with command, you do it in normal mode. First go to the mark `t` , then:

```
>'b
```

The block will be shifted and the cursor will be still on mark `t`.

Comment: `:%s/nrom/norm`